# How to change the name of the DLL & project& solution of a custom control and use it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

then update the windows forms application where the control is used to reference the new DLL for the custom control

I created a custom control that I use in a windows forms application I wrote.
I created a separate project so I could use the control in multiple applications.
It was written in C# using VS 2010 .
The way I understand it the custom control resides in the DLL.
I imported the control to my tool box in my current application and it seems to work fine.
For revision control and appropriate naming purposes I need to rename the project & solution & DLL (I think I want them all to have the same name)  I use to create the custom control.
This will change the name of the DLL that the controls resides in……me thinks.
I grepped my current application and I found two references to the old DLL which still exists but since I renamed the project now there is a DLL with the new name.
I tried to import the control from the newly named DLL which worked but when I tried to replace the references to the old DLL to the new one it wreaked all kinds of inexplicable havoc
How do I get the my current application to use the same old control but from a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The way that we handle this particular issue for our own controls, and the way that several third-party control vendors do this, is to leave the namespace intact, but just change the DLL name (i.e. MyControl.v11.1.dll).

Then, when it is time to upgrade the control, you edit the project file, change the DLL name, and you are off and running.

We use a couple of tricks in order to make this as smooth as possible when dealing with both our controls and third party controls.

First, we always copy a version of the DLL to a directory that is relative to the project. This way, if the developer upgrades their machine to a more recent version, it won't be accidentally built into the app.

Second, we always ensure the DLL references in the project and licenses.licx files have the version and public key information removed.

Finally, we manually edit the project file to ensure the project does not require a specific version and that it is referencing the local copy of the assembly.

Here is an example of an entry from our project file with all of the above applied:

```
<Reference Include="Controls.v11.1">
  <HintPath>..\..\Assemblies\Controls.v11.1.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

We have successfully used this approach for our projects for at least 8 years and since we implemented this approach, we haven't had any DLL upgrade issues.